# URL pattern to exclude globally in Zap

Tags: regex, owasp, zap

I am having trouble with regex syntax in OWASP ZAP. I want to exclude from all scans all URLs that contain "web/lib". I've tried to add

```
^*web/lib*$
```

under Global Exclude URL option, but it didn't work. Please help - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's regex, if you're specifying wildcard you generally want period asterisk. You also probably need to escape the slash.

Eg: https://regex101.com/r/XLPF85/1